# As3 flash error “Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference”

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I came up with this error when testing my movie

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at ACTUALPROJECT_fla::MainTimeline/youLose()[ACTUALPROJECT_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:112]
    at ACTUALPROJECT_fla::MainTimeline/SharkEat()[ACTUALPROJECT_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:87]
```

**this is my code**

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;

var rectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,345,600,455);

turtle_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
turtle_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
turtle_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision);
turtle_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision2);
turtle_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision4);
turtle_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, SharkEat);
turtle_mc.buttonMode = true;
turtle_mc.originalY = turtle_mc.y;
turtle_mc.originalX = turtle_mc.x;

function resetTurtlePosition()
{
    turtle_mc.y = turtle_mc.originalY;
    turtle_mc.x = turtle_mc.originalX;
}

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag(false, rectangle);
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
}


function handleCollision(e:Event):void
{


    if (plasticBag_mc.hitTestPoint(turtle_mc.x,turtle_mc.y,false))
    {

        youLose();

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
function handleCollision2(e:Event):void
{


    if (fishingBoat_mc.hitTestPoint(turtle_mc.x,turtle_mc.y,false))
    {

        youLose();

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
function handleCollision4(e:Event):void
{


    if (oilSpillBoat_mc.hitTestPoint(turtle_mc.x,turtle_mc.y,false))
    {

        youLose();

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
function SharkEat(e:Event):void
{


    if (shark_mc.hitTestPoint(turtle_mc.x,turtle_mc.y,false))
    {

        **youLose();**

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
var nCount:Number = 0;
var myScore:Timer = new Timer(10,nCount);
counter_txt.text = nCount.toString();
myScore.start();
myScore.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    nCount++;
    counter_txt.text = nCount.toString();

}

function youLose():void
{
    myScore.stop();
    turtle_mc.stopDrag();
    resetTurtlePosition();
    **this.storedtxt = counter_txt.text;**
    gotoAndStop(3,"PlayTheGame");
}
```

i have marked the two lines with asterix.
I'm new to flash and Action Script-3, can anyone help me out?

Comment: @akmozo how do I declare it... sorry I'm new to flash as mentioned. and this problem only arised after adding in the 'SharkEat' function. It didn't when it wasn't there earlier.

Comment: @akmozo `storedtxt` will be used to store the text in `counter_txt` for use in another frame

Comment: @amkozo the same error still comes up... funny thing is that there doesn't seem to be a problem when i run the SWF, just that the errors annoy me....

Comment: Sorry, but forget all about `storedtxt` and `counter_txt` and take a look on my answer ... I'll delete all my comments because they are useless ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-verifying your code, I think that your error is coming from this line :

```
gotoAndStop(3,"PlayTheGame");
```

because the `EnterFrame` event on your `turtle_mc` object is still being fired even after going to the 3rd frame of your `PlayTheGame` scene, and that's why you got that error because some objects used in your `EnterFrame` event handlers doesn't exist in that frame.

So to avoid that, you can do like this :

// you should know that you can use a single handler to handle all collisions

```
turtle_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision);

function handleCollision(e:Event):void
{
    if (        
        plasticBag_mc.hitTestPoint(turtle_mc.x,turtle_mc.y,false) ||
        fishingBoat_mc.hitTestPoint(turtle_mc.x,turtle_mc.y,false) ||
        oilSpillBoat_mc.hitTestPoint(turtle_mc.x,turtle_mc.y,false) ||
        shark_mc.hitTestPoint(turtle_mc.x,turtle_mc.y,false))       
    {
        youLose();
    }
    else {}
}
```

then in your `youLose()` function, you should remove the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event listener before going to the other scene :

```
function youLose():void
{
    // ...

    turtle_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision);

    gotoAndStop(3, 'PlayTheGame');
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: worked like a charm! I'm so happy you could help! Thank you akmozo :)